# Initialize USB keyboard attached while suspended

Tags: usb, kubuntu, suspend, 14.10

I have a laptop that I sometimes want to use with separate peripherals; external monitor, external keyboard and external mouse. When in this mode, I want to keep the laptop closed and tucked away (as much as cooling concerns allow ;)

I would like to simply attach the peripherals and then tap the external keyboard to wake the computer. This does not work -- it does not respond to keypresses on the external keyboard -- so I have to wake it by opening the lid. When awake, it recognizes the keyboard and does some kind of initialization. I can then close the lid, which causes the machine to go back to sleep, and wake the computer with the external keyboard.

This is more roundabout than I would like.

How can I make the machine recognize the external keyboard when I attach it while the machine is suspended?

Comment: (Workarounds, such as "wake on attaching an external monitor" would also be welcome :)

Comment: My hardware is a `MacBookPro10,2`, according to `dmidecode` :)

Comment: Also maybe worth noting; When I attach the keyboard while the machine is sleeping, all the indicator lights on the keyboard (caps, scroll and num lock) go on and stay on until the machine wakes. I take this as an indication that USB is powered, but that there is no data traffic.

Comment: I've just the last couple of days had need to look at udev rules, Magnus. I'm a real amateur with them so cannot give you an answer as such, but suggest you research the topic? The rules allow (amongst other things) for certain actions to take place when hardware is detected.

Comment: I have looked at udev before, and I find it a large topic. As far as I know, it only defines rules for what happens while the machine is already awake. Do you know different, @ClivevanHilten?

Comment: Sorry @Magnus, I don't know any more. It is indeed a large and frankly bewildering topic.